# Wrap Content grid view items with span count

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager having column span 4,
I am able to achieve below output [image]  with following code

```
recyclerGridLayout.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, rowSpacing, columnSpacing));
recyclerGridLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerGridLayout.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));
```

But is there any way i can get the below desired output
[image]

Where the space between items is fixed

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solved using FlexBoxLayoutManager,
To get fixed space between items and to get fix number of items per row or so to say to set spanCount like in gridlayoutManager,
OnBindViewHolder, we do the following

```
FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setWrapBefore(position != 0 && (position % 4 == 0)); //4 is spanCount
itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

And while configuring recyclerview, we use

```
FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(mContext, FlexDirection.ROW, FlexWrap.WRAP);  
flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
recyclerGridLayout.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 3 column span to 4.
e.g.:

```
recyclerGridLayout.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
```

Comment: number of items per row is not an issue here, The space between items if we see in 1st image is variable, but i need the space between items to be constant just like 2nd image